# VGA out video is wavy and unreadable with a ATI Radeon X1200

Tags: 10.04, ati, external-monitor, output

Trying to get stable output when using monitor attached to VGA port on gateway netbook  running lucid Lynx 10.04LTS.  Monitor video is wavy and unreadable.

Video card is an ati radeon X1200.  Current LCD resolution is set to 1280 x 768.  Refresh is set to 0 and can't be changed.  No other selectable resolution options are offered.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a fix:

Create file /etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf
Then add the next line:
options radeon new_pll=0 modeset=0

Reboot

Via
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9224574&postcount=8

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my father have this problem, if you have a screen more bigger than 32" this problem no disappear.In this moment the problem no have repair.